# decimal value is displayed in scientific notation - HBase (Phoenix)

Tags: java, apache-spark, hbase, apache-phoenix, scientific-notation

is it possible to display actual decimal value rather than to display in scientific notation in HBase Shell?

Created HBase table via Phoenix script mentioned below. Populated data (*"loginTime":0.000064444*) into this HBase table (created via phoenix script) via Spark job in java.

If the java datatype for this field is *Double*, then the value is getting displayed in scientific notation as "*6.44443E-5*" instead of displaying actual value. But if I make the java datatype is *String*, then actual value is getting displayed. How to get the actual value without scientific notation with java datatype as *Double*?

**Phoenix Script**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "LOGIN_TABLE"(recordId VARCHAR,
"FACTS"."loginTime" VARCHAR,
CONSTRAINT "LOGIN_TABLE_PK" Primary Key(recordId)) SALT_BUCKETS = 4
```

**Java Pojo**

```
public class TestObject {
 private Double loginTime;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using java datatype java.math.BigDecimal instead of java.lang.Double resolved the issue. After using BigDecimal, HBase is getting populated with actual value instead of scientific notation.